# Is it possible to initialise UIImage with PDF remote data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

According to the docs of [UIImage.init(with: Data)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624106-init) and the data parameter:

> The data in the data parameter must be formatted to match the file format of one of the system’s supported image types.

I assumed that it will be possible to initialise `UIImage` when passing PDF data to this init (since iOS supports PDF vector assets) but unfortunately I'm getting `nil` from this init. Am I doing something wrong or it's not possible to use PDFs as remote assets?

**I don't have this PDF data locally, it's fetched from the backend.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jake's response I found the way to achieve what I need just passing Data as a parameter, not url as on jake's answer.

Full extension for `UIImage`:

```swift
import UIKit
import PDFKit
import CoreGraphics

extension UIImage {
    public static func fromPDF(data: Data) -> UIImage? {
        guard
            let pdf = PDFDocument(data: data),
            let pdfPage = pdf.page(at: 0),
            let pageRef = pdfPage.pageRef
        else { return nil }

        let pageRect = pageRef.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            UIColor.clear.set()
            ctx.fill(pageRect)

            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
            ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

            ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(pageRef)
        }
        return img
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` or `ImageContext` for this one. For the former (iOS >10), you could try this code here:

```
func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    // First page of the document.
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()
        ctx.fill(pageRect)

        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return img
}
```

Hope that helps.